# MYSQL lessen execution time of multiple sub query

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have 3 tables in my database, i am querying thousands of records which makes my query slow, my main query has two sub queries which counts records. Although im getting my desired output i just want to know if there are another ways to lessen the execution time of my query to become efficient.

**Desired output**
classid - classcode - assessedinclass - validatedinclass

using this sql query a 500+ record is executed about 2 minutes

`SELECT
mainclass.id,
mainclass.code,
 (SELECT
        Count(e.enrollno)
        FROM
        enrolldet AS e
        Inner Join enroll ON e.enrollno = enroll.enrollno
        Inner Join class ON e.classid= class.id
        WHERE
        enroll.assessed =  '1' AND
        mainclass.id =  class.id) as assessedinclass,
 (SELECT
        Count(e.enrollno)
        FROM
        enrolldet AS e
        Inner Join enroll ON e.enrollno = enroll.enrollno
        Inner Join class ON e.classid= class.id
        WHERE
        enroll.validated =  '1' AND
        mainclass.id =  class.id) as validatedinclass
FROM
class AS mainclass
Left Join enrolldet ON mainclass.id = enrolldet.classid
Left Join enroll ON enrolldet.enrollno = enroll.enrollno
GROUP BY
mainclass.id,
mainclass.code`

**Database**

### table `class`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `class` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `subject` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `class`

INSERT INTO `class` (`id`, `code`, `subject`) VALUES
(1, 'A1', 1),
(2, 'A2', 2),
(3, 'A3', 3),
(4, 'A4', 4);

### table `enroll`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `enroll` (
  `enrollno` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `acctok` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `assessed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `validated` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`enrollno`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `enroll`

```
INSERT INTO `enroll` (`enrollno`, `student`, `acctok`, `assessed`, `validated`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1, 0),
(2, 2, 1, 1, 1),
(3, 3, 1, 1, 0),
(4, 4, 0, 0, 0),
(5, 5, 1, 1, 1);
```

### table `enrolldet`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `enrolldet` (
  `enrollno` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `classid` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

--

### -- Dumping data for table `enrolldet`

```
INSERT INTO `enrolldet` (`enrollno`, `classid`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 4),
(2, 1),
(2, 2),
(2, 3),
(2, 4),
(3, 1),
(3, 2),
(3, 3),
(3, 4),
(4, 1),
(4, 2),
(4, 3),
(4, 4),
(5, 1),
(5, 2),
(5, 3);
```

I only added few records in my sample, but i have thousands of records to display. is there any better query for this? thanks in advance

Comment: did you already added indexes in your columns?

Comment: For enrolldet I'd make both columns a composite primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Sum the expression rather than a subquery. Using `JOIN`s rather than `LEFT JOIN` will save some record retrieval assuming there is always a match.

```
SELECT class.id, class.code,
  SUM(enroll.assessed =  '1') as assessedinclass,
  SUM(enroll.validated =  '1') as validatedinclass
FROM class
JOIN enrolldet ON class.id = enrolldet.classid
JOIN enroll ON enrolldet.enrollno = enroll.enrollno
GROUP BY class.id, class.code
```

Comment: i used left join because i still want to retrieve the CLASS even there is no match and i want the ASSESSED and VALIDATED return 0

Comment: There is no filtering criteria on assessed/validated (though you could if these represented a small number of rows and where indexed). Is there always a enrolldet for a class, and a enroll for an enrolldet? If no, the a LEFT JOIN is appropriate to get a 0 result.

Comment: no, sometimes class and enroll is not in the enrolldet, therefore i have a record wherein the class details are displayed but the number of assessed and validated enrollment are 0.

Comment: ive tried running the code, i am expected to get 506 total records from CLASS but i only got 357, i supposed it only get the records with ASSESSED value = 1

Comment: If you `LEFT JOIN` on the same query you should get the `{assessed|validated}inclass=0` for those classes without a corresponding `enrolldet`/`enroll` entries.